# Uso do sinal "—" em prosa

Tags: pontuação

Quando leio texto em prosa(romances, policiais, etc), de quando em vez encontro um sinal que se parece com um hífen, mas mais comprido: “—”. Um travessão? Já não me lembro bem...

Quais as regras para o seu uso? não me parece algo normalizado, dado que cada autor parece dar-lhe uma funcionalidade algo diferente (posso estar errado).

Serve para algo com um aparte? Por exemplo, na frase anterior, escrevi, entre parêntesis, «posso estar errado». Poderia ter escrito com um travessão?

Qualquer ajudar será bem-vinda.

Comment: Depende do autor, mas eu, pelo menos, não o uso para apartes. Acho que é mais para explicações ou acrescentar detalhes. "Ela tinha um casaco amarelo - belo e detalhado" "Geralmente, um byte contém 8 bits - a unidade básica de informação, com dois possíveis estados."